# Understanding the best before code for yoshon

Tags: yashan-chadash

[COR: Canadian Yoshon Guide](https://www.cor.ca/view/767/20165777_canadian_yoshon_update_2.html.html) writes:

> **Quaker Oats (COR 112)**: All products containing oats and/or oat bran - date code of **0819P8** or earlier (Family Size will have a ‘TV’ code instead of ‘P’).

.

Would the best before code on a Quaker oatmeal box of "20 AL 11 **0417P9** 16" qualify for yashan?

Comment: You should ask Quaker how to understand their codes. They would know.

Comment: I looked at this. The 0819P8 is likely not a date code but rather a manufacturing number. The date comes before, e.g., 20 AL 11 in your example is a best by date of April 11, 2020. The website of COR now shows 0915P9 or earlier so it is likely that 0417P9 comes before 0915P9 but there is no way to be sure. I have asked Quaker and will report back when they respond